# Polymer attribute changed function

Tags: polymer, web-component

I have an element defined with currency and price attributes. When I set the currency attribute to British pound, I want to calculate price accordingly. I tried hooking the attrChanged method but the the if condition never logs true

```
currencyChanged: function (attrName, oldVal, newVal) {

    var actualPrice = this.getAttribute("usdprice");
    actualPrice = parseInt(actualPrice);

    var converter = 1;

    if(newVal === "£") {
      converter = 0.59;
      console.log("true");
    }

    this.$.price.innerHTML = actualPrice*converter;
  }
```

I change the currency using the below command

```
var a = document.querySelector("gmselect-element"); 
a.setAttribute("currency", "£");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use [published property *Changed watchers](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#change-watchers) like `currencyChanged` the arguments are (oldVal, newVal). It's only when you create a generic [`attributeChanged` lifecycle method](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#lifecyclemethods) that you get (attrName, oldVal, newVal). Try this:

```
currencyChanged: function (oldVal, newVal) {

    var actualPrice = this.getAttribute("usdprice");
    actualPrice = parseInt(actualPrice);

    var converter = 1;

    if(newVal === "£") {
      converter = 0.59;
      console.log("true");
    }

    this.$.price.innerHTML = actualPrice*converter;
  }
```

Open the Dev Tools console on [this simplified jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nocoxuzo/1/edit?html,output) to see it working.